# Improve performance ravendb index

Tags: c#, .net, performance, indexing, ravendb

Considering this scenario:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
}

class Student : Person
{
}

class Worker : Person
{
}

class PersonViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<PersonViewModel>
{
    public PersonIndex()
    {
        AddMapForAll<Person>(docs => from doc in docs
                                     select new PersonViewModel
                                     {
                                         Id = doc.Id,
                                         Name = doc.Name,
                                         Surname = doc.Surname,
                                         FullName = doc.Name + " " + doc.SecondName + " " + doc.Surname
                                     });

        StoreAllFields(FieldStorage.Yes);

        Indexes.Add(x => x.Id, FieldIndexing.No);
        Indexes.Add(x => x.FullName, FieldIndexing.No);

        Indexes.Add(x => x.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Indexes.Add(x => x.Surname, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}

var queryResult = session.Query<PersonViewModel, PersonIndex>()
                                .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("A"))
                                .Where(x => x.Surname.StartsWith("C"))
                                .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<PersonViewModel>()
                                .ToList();
```

This is only an example, in my scenario i've 7/8 indexes like this with more mapped fields and the original class Person is extended by more than 2 classes (15 min).
Each of these indexes about 5000 documents.

What can I do to improve my index and performance?

Comment: What is your current performance?

Comment: @AyendeRahien when i update the index, reindexing all documents take 10/15/20 minutes, is that normal timing?

Comment: How many documents do you have? Note that you are storing all fields, and also have full text search enabled there.

Comment: @AyendeRahien i'm storing all fields because i need these fields (isn't correct?) and i also need full text search on name and surname;
from 4000 to 10000 docs each index

Comment: Note that this is probably better handled in the mailing list.
You don't need to store all fields in the index usually. Where are you running this?

Comment: @AyendeRahien win. server 2012;
i need to store all fields because i need all values of the mapped fields.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your query, it looks like you are interested in selected records where "Name" or "Surname" start with a specific letter.

Have you considered modifying your collection to have fields with this kind of information?  For example, if you have a "Name: Michael" and a "Surname: Smith", maybe you should also have a "FirstLetterName: M" and "FirstLetterSurname: S" and add an index for those fields.

Comment: "A" and "C" are only an example, they could be "ant" and "cho";
In fact I used FieldIndexing.Analyzed to those fields where i need a full text search;